# Unvalidated DB output in checkmarx

Tags: java, collections, checkmarx

Unvalidated DB output was found at line 123. A possible XSS exploitation was found in @DestinationElement at line number 123.

Issue Name: Stored_XSS

Line 123: List listFile = Arrays.asList(file.listFiles());

How to resolve this checkmarx issue?

Comment: You're missing quite a bit of information from your question, such as other parts of code and such, but it seems pretty clear that you need to be HTML encoding the data you pulled from the database, before sending it to the output. I would be surprised if that recommendation didn't already appear in your report...